# mdadm - Recovering a 'split' RAID1 array

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have two drives that used to be part of a single RAID1 volume but it appears that one of them went offline for some time, something I've noticed just now when I rebooted my system.

I now seem to have two RAID volumes, as reported by:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdc[1]
      2096116 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb[0]
      2096116 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

Not exactly sure where to go from here. How can I merge and re-sync these volumes without data loss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to find out which of the two devices has the more recent copy of the RAID. Try to mount them read-only and look at the files. The logs (esp. `/var/log/syslog*`) might help here too. Then you have to verify that the drive that went offline isn't broken (logs, again, and SMART).

Then kill the other raid (`mdadm --fail`, `mdadm --remove`) and add the device to the correct one. This will trigger a resync, but then you should have a fine raid again.

Comment: The disks/partitions that are showing "U" are the ones that will be most up-to-date. There is no need to check the now out-of-date disks as mdadm knows which one is most current.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to re-add the disk with the `-a` option. For example:

```
mdadm -a /dev/md127 /dev/sdc1
```

Use `mdadm -D /dev/mddevice` to get more information about the array. You may need to use `-r` option first to remove the problematic disk partition before re-adding

Comment: I had to do mdadm --stop /dev/md126 before adding it again